# How to provide SASS variables/mixins/etc alongside with Rollup build?

Tags: sass, rollup

The idea is simple. I have npm package which is using Rollup and it has some sass variables and mixins. And I need to provide them with the package, so in projects which are using my package the users could just:

`SomeProject/styles/main.sass`:

```
@import '~my-lib/dist/sass/mixins` // or something like this

.custom-class
  // some stuff
  @mixin-from-my-lib
```

So, in order to make this work I have to put my `mixins.sass` in the `dist` somehow. And I don't have any ideas.

It's probably a couple of lines in rollup.config.js, but I just can't find anything related to this. :(